# SQL Server date conversion not is formatting the output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

My SQL statement is supposed to add 5 days to the date column and reformat the output to MM/DD/YYYY.

The calculation is working, but the format won't change, no matter what value I use.

The date column is defined as `varchar(128)` (I've used `datetime` and `varchar(128)` in the convert statement).

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
    FSI_Date, DATEADD("d", +5, CONVERT(DATE, FSI_Date, 101)) AS NEWDAY,
FROM
    DB_test

FSI_Date       NEWDAY
---------------------------
12/12/2015     2015-12-17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server will convert `mm/dd/yyyy` to a date, so, you just need the `dateadd()` and then convert back to your desired format.

Remove the final `convert(...,101)` if you want a natural date.

**Example**

```
Select FSI_Date
      ,NewDay = convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(DAY,5,@FSI_Date),101)
 From  DB_Test
```

**Returns**

```
FSI_Date            NewDay
12/12/2015          12/17/2015
```